Show console or make GUI display for script progress using Python TKInter
I have made a exe launcher of sorts, that combines many scripts into one monolithic script with different tabs in a TKinter GUI for the different scripts, for most of the mini programs clicking on a button on their tab opens the specific program in a TKinter screen, where they run normally.
However, 2 of my scripts/programs run in the console when they are run (in there own exe or through vscode) the launcher, is its own one file exe and therefore does not show the CMD window on running when the button is clicked. I have tried several ways to display the data, but none of them worked at all.
Is there a way to make the CMD based scripts either display the terminal or build a label/textbox screen to update on the progress as it runs the script?
Each script sits within its own.
def cmd_script() function
I'm a bit lost for ideas here, any would be really appreciated.
